# How to enable horizontal scrolling in Django Admin list view?

Tags: django, django-admin

I really like the Django Admin list view. I would like to show ~30 fields of one table in the list, however my issue is that horizontal scroll bar is not visible in the list view even though data overflows right border. How can I enable scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an open bug in Django: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26066

If you are fine with the problems stated in that issue you could just add some css code:

```
#changelist-form .results {
  /*overflow-x: auto;*/
}
```

But if you have an even better solution you could always overwrite the default templates [quite easily](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/overriding-templates/).  Just add a `change_list.html` and add your custom code there. See the original change_list.html for [reference](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html):

Comment: Thanks! Changing the CSS creates a scroll bar but it belongs to the table, so one has to scroll first to the bottom - would be much more convenient to have the scrollbar on the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post/method worked nicely for me. It applied a scroll bar to the table view only thus making it easy to navigate:

https://til.simonwillison.net/django/django-admin-horizontal-scroll